# Google App - Doesn't Populate Spreadsheet Cell During Script Run using Debug

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know how Google App's work when we step through during debug? For example, some action will reflect in the sheet itself while stepping through the code (IE: inserting a row) and some other actions will not (IE: populating getRange(a,b,).setValue(1) into the specified cell) until the code is finish running or breaks. Does anyone know what will update instantly and what wouldn't? Right now I'm having my code depend on some of those instant updates and it's not working out very well. thanks!

Comment: You can also use `Logger.log()` statements to print information to the LOG.  And also VIEW the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT.  You may need to comment out sections of code, in order to isolate what you are focusing on.  Don't know why debug does that.  Interestingly, if I set a value, and then get that value in debug, stepping through, the code gets the value, and the spreadsheet updates.

Comment: hi pnuts, thanks for the reply. I know how to view the variable value in log and such. What I want is for it to appear in the actual cell so my loop can grab that newly updated cell and do things based off of it. Stepping through in the debug doesn't populate the cell for me either it seems. Thus I kinda want to know if there's a glossary or something that tells me when things populate so I know what I can and can't do during code logic  conception.

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheet will be caching the writes to the spreadsheet. You can force the changes to appear with [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()), although you'll probably want to take these out of the production code as it'll [slow everything down](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices).